# Cannot remove components (Attempted to remove a component that does not exist)

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a component with a number of sub components. In the following code, I get the component, and then get all its child components with '**cls=ngp**'. Then I iterate over them and try to remove them from the parent panel.

```
    var ptp = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('partytoolpanel')[0]; //there is only ever one instance!!

    var comps = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('partytoolpanel [cls=ngp]') //6 objects are returned here!!

    comps.forEach(function (c) {
        ptp.remove(c);
    })
```

The **comps** are not removed, instead I get this message :

> Attempted to remove a component that does not exist.
>   Ext.container.Container: remove takes an argument of the component to
>   remove. cmp.remove() is incorrect usage.

I tried to duplicate this problem in a fiddle, and, of course, it works perfectly :(
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1irm

Why would my case not work?

Comment: Could it be that cls=ngp is also on the container?  You could try:
_var comps = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[cls=ngp]',ptp )_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component query `partytoolpanel [cls=ngp]` will match all components with that class which are somewhere in the hierarchy below the component with `xtype: 'partytool'`, not just direct children.

But the `container.remove` function can only remove components that are direct children of `container`.

You should remove the components from their direct parent inside your loop:

```
Ext.each(comps, function (c) {
    c.up().remove(c);
})
```

(I recommend that you use `Ext.each(array, fn)` instead of `array.forEach(fn)`, so Sencha can take care of any browser issues.)